# TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable + using docker image

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, pydoc

I am loading the class dynamically in python using pydoc locate. The class loads successfully when I run the project from eclipse.

```
from pydoc import locate
my_class = locate('my_package.my_module.MyClass')
my_instance =my_class()
```

Now, I created a Dockerfile and the docker build is successful. When I run the docker image, the class is not loaded and instance is not created. It shows this error

> TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable

Comment: In this case, it might be useful to include your `dockerfile` in the question. Have you tried to connect to your running container and run your project in interactive session?

Answer (score 1):

In docker file

ADD my_package/my_module/*.py